# Dual Boot 64 bit Windos 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

64 bit Windows 7 is in the machine. I Download 64bit iso file and make a CD. I set the BIOS, let the CD Drive as the first Boot option. When I tried to Install Ubuntu, it starts the process as normal.

Windows 7 is in Drive 'C'. As a came to know, It should recognize the existing O/s withing the process and should appear it on the Monitor. but the machine says there is no O/s, so Choose 'C' or some where else. In addition it says, I will loose just my Data files.

So I stooped the Process to avoid loosing my existing o/s. I tried it several times and got the same experience.

Then I boot Windows 7 and run 'Wubi' file. The first window is appearing normal. I can select the Drive where to Install Ubuntu & selected the Quota for Ubuntu, user name, password. When I continue, it goes to next window and doing some process for few seconds. Then the Process is stop (critical Stop), and the massage says, it cannot find disk images.

It happens again and again.

Can somebody guide me pls ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an installer for Windows 7? Because if you do I would recommend you to install Ubuntu first and leave some space for Windows. Then install Windows and repair install the blootloader using a software called Easy BCD.

Comment: boot-repair is a nice tool - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: That's right. You can also use boot-repair to install Grub2. However, the reason why I recommend Easy BCD is because since the person is already booted in Windows, it is much faster to install and use Easy BCD than to boot with a live disk again and use boot-repair which takes its time.

Comment: It's a good option and thank you. I don't have a genuine CD of Windows 7. So I have to decide whether I keep the original O/s and give up the Love to Ubuntu, or delete original O/s for my thirst of Knowledge :-) Thanks again Chetan !

Comment: By the way what version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? I recommend you try the standard install with Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. The latest version is having problems with some machines (including mine).